# function param and let/const with same name throws an error

Tags: javascript

So here I am having let and function param with same name which throws an error can somebody help me with whats happening around?

```
function foo(x, y) {
  var x = 10; // Allowed
  let y = 5;  // SyntaxError: Identifier 'y' has already been declared
  return x + y;
}
```

Comment: why you're defining the variables with same name ? when you have those names already in arguments ? and here point is var allow you to define the same variable again whereas let don't allow re-deceleration of same variable

Comment: Function parameters are mostly like having a variable declared with `var` at the top of the block. A duplicate `var` declaration of a variable name already used is permitted, but a duplicate `let` declaration of a variable name already used is not

Comment: The variables declared with cannot be re-declared. but with var, It will overwrite the old one

Comment: yeah @Shareef That's the fact I am keen about what's happening under the hood

Comment: @CodeManiac I know it's bad practice but as I mentioned I was more interested in the explanation why it's doing so

Comment: @Hiral i have given explanation in my comment why is happening so `here point is var allow you to define the same variable again whereas let don't allow re-deceleration of same variable`

Comment: @Hiral And there comes TDZ (Temporal Dead Zone) for all those ES6 declarations which doesn't let you re-declare or use before their declarations.

Comment: Thanks @MadhusudhanDollu read few articles about TDZ it explains it well.